# Backup Database and Gzip the Backup

Tags: cron

I'm backing up my database for 7 days and this is working fine.
My Backups getting compressed to gzip files. But here is the problem. The "normal" backup has 13 Gb and the gzip just compress this to 11 Gb.
Is there a possibility to compress it even more?
If I compress it via Backend of Mysql it has just some few Mb.

My Cronjob to this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
find /home/backup_db -type f -ctime +7 -exec rm -f{} \;
now =$(date + "%m_%d_%Y")
mysqldump -user -passwort > /home/backup_db/mysql_$now.dump
gzip /home/backup_db/*.dump
```

Comment: It depends on the data in the database but usually bzip2 and zstd compressed more than gzip. You can also explore `gzip -9` option.

Comment: @JoãoAlves The data in the database are mostly .png .pdf .jpg .gif and .tiff

Comment: Images typically have already been compressed and further applying gzip will not achieve large savings.

Comment: @tater still if they are saved as a blob file? I cant compress it another way?

Comment: You can get some idea of potential savings by running gzip on the images themselves. Generally BLOB data (if dumped as binary) is just the images themselves with an insignificant amount of text added around it for the `INSERT`, and is therefore about as compressible as the raw images.